# Swamp Cooler switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I would like to take this swamp cooler switch off the wall since I now have central air. What are the chances/How do I know if it isn't connected to something else like a light switch or plug and if I cap the wires off another light switch or plug will no longer work?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's more wires than a simple switch should require. Unfortunately I can't guess what else is going on, not knowing what sort of switch it is.

Comment: A photograph of the front of the switch would help. Is it a two-speed swamp cooler? Aside: Where is the box in the wall that contains the fire? Or is that low voltage wiring?

Comment: I added a picture of the face plate.

Comment: On the basis of the faceplate I'm guessing that the switch has three separate outputs: fan low speed, fan high speed, and pump. Combinations of those give you the five operational settings. That would lead me to suspect that the white wire connected to the switch isn't neutral and ought to be marked as a hot lead. Can you describe how the wires are cabled? The first pictures doesn't show us how they are grouped together in the wall, nor whether there are any connections, e.g. wire nuts, in the wall that join some other wires.

Comment: There is one wire nut in there with 2 white, I'm assuming hot, wires to it.  No wires that I can see from the switch are connected to the wire nut.  They all just disappear going up in the wall.  There is a bathroom on the other side of the wall.
I really appreciate your help - Thanks

Comment: [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess): From the breaker/fuse box a 12/2 cable with white (neutral) and black (hot); to the pump from the switch a 12/2 cable with white (neutral) and black (hot); to the fan from the switch a 12/2 cable with white (**hot**, low speed?) and black (hot, high speed?). The source and pump neutrals (two whites) are connected with a wire nut. The fan gets its neutral from the pump cable at the swamp cooler. (Hopefully there are grounds connected together.) NB: A white wire used as a hot **MUST** be marked, e.g. with black tape at both ends.

Comment: This sounds about right from what I can understand from it.  Will I be able to cap off the wires and remove the switch with out worrying there are other light switches or plugs connected together with it?

Comment: Since all of the conductors are accounted for and all of the hot leads to the swamp cooler are switched, there can't be any other always-on circuits connected beyond the switch. Ideally you would (with the power off) tag the wires to identify where they go, disconnect them and cap them with wire nuts. The third photograph shows a hint of what might be brown phenolic electrical box. If so, add a blank cover plate and you're done. Unboxed connections in a wall are, as a rule, NEC code violations.